# why does my flask app doesn't show with nginx

Tags: nginx, flask

i want to serve my flask app with nginx following this tutorial [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

after i finished the tutorial, when i go to `http://0.0.0.0` it show default welcome to nginx instead of my flask app. according to tutorial, i should have my flask app.

this is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/farhan/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

and this is my service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=farhan
Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/home/farhan/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/farhan/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/farhan/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

what's wrong with my configuration? any answer would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: You should go to `http://127.0.0.1`, not `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: it still direct to nginx welcome homepage, fyi my flask app url is http://0.0.0.0:5000 @Selcuk

Comment: You are using Unix sockets, not TCP sockets, so `5000` is irrelevant here. You seem to have another nginx config file than you posted above, post that too.

Comment: i just have one nginx config @Selcuk

Comment: Where does it find the location of your default welcome page then?

Comment: Please include output of `sudo journalctl -u nginx` command so we can see nginx logs,

Answer (score 0):

By default nginx uses port `80` so you can't reuse it for something else
so you can either change it to listen on another port or you can change the `default` nginx config file to listen on another port other than 80

note that all nginx config files located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

then you should make a hard link that points to it inside the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory by writing this command:

```
sudo ln /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

then it should work